# AngularJS $destroy on $rootscope never gets called to cancel timeouts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, destroy

I have the following code -

```js
function initialize() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  var deferTimer = $q.defer();

  var cancelTimeout = $timeout(function() {
    if (defer !== null) {
      ctrlr.setProcessingParameters('XXX');
      defer = ctrlr.openProgressBar();
      deferTimer.resolve();
    }
  }, 1000);

  deferTimer.promise.then(function() {
    var cancelTimeout2 = $timeout(function() {
      if (defer !== null) {
        defer.resolve();
        ctrlr.setProcessingParameters('Please Wait...');
        defer = ctrlr.openProgressBar();
      }
    }, 4000);
  });

  //Process Backend service n resolbve defer....

}

// cancel the $timeout service
$rootScope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  logger.log("cancelTimeout..timer..");
  if (cancelTimeout) {
    $timeout.cancel(cancelTimeoutProcess);
    cancelTimeout = null;
  }
});

// cancel the $timeout service
$rootScope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  logger.log("cancelTimeout2..timer..")
  if (cancelTimeout2) {
    $timeout.cancel(cancelTimeout2);
    cancelTimeout2 = null;
  }
});
```

I do not see the loggers print or debugger gets into `$destroy`. Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: I don't know why it's not getting into the `$rootScope.$on('$destroy'` function but surely `cancelTimeout` and `cancelTimeout2` would throw an error anyway as they're scoped to the `initialize` function?

Comment: @George if i add it as global variables, that should resolve the issue right? I heard we should not be using cancel timer logic inside any fn.

Comment: `$rootScope` gets destroyed when you close or leave the page. Everything will be gone then, so there's nothing to clean up..

Comment: @tanmay then how can i cancel / kill those timeouts?

Comment: @Smitha you don't have access to `$scope`?

Comment: @tanmay Yes, I do have. but its same as $rootscope right? gets destroyed when you close or leave the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rootScope` gets destroyed when you close or leave the page. Everything will be gone then, so there's nothing to clean up at that time.

What you are looking for is `$destroy` on `$scope` instead,

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  logger.log("cancelTimeout..timer..");
  if (cancelTimeout) {
    $timeout.cancel(cancelTimeoutProcess);
    cancelTimeout = null;
  }
});
```

While in the controller, `$scope.$on('$destroy'..` will be called when controller gets destroyed (and not the whole application) with which current `$scope` is associated.